# My professor did not cite my article in a review on the same topic

Tags: citations, ethics

I was surprised to see a review on a topic where I have published an original article, where my article was not cited. My surprise was even bigger because this review was issued from the same department where my original article was issued and it was concerning the same topic. The first author was somebody I don't know personally, but the corresponding author is my professor, who was also a co-author in my original article. I must also say that my original article has many international citations, and it saddened me a lot to realize that my own department and my own professor, forgot to cite my (their) own published work.

I emailed my professor the fact that I felt forgotten and that this was not academically correct but the answer I received did not make things better. He said that

> many other articles aren't included, because this review was covering
>   many topics and that the main topic was "A". The part of the topic B
>   (my topic) was not included in the aim of the review but was asked by
>   a reviewer so it was added later.

But I'm not happy with this answer, because the topic B is even included in the main title of the review. But even the topic A could be enough for a citation of my original article. Later he said that in a review article they can cite only the recent 2 years original articles and that he was not obliged to cite my (our) original article.

I have obtained my PhD from this department, 5 years ago, and my original article was published 5 years ago. The review was published last month.

Do you believe that this was academically correct?

Comment: "Later he said that in a review article they can cite only the recent 2 years original articles." And is that actually the case: i.e., did someone write a review article on a topic in which the only citations were to papers published within the last two years?  (I would find that amazing.)  This seems like a definitive question: if this is indeed the practice, then the practice might be weird but that's a reason he didn't cite a ton of other work.  If it isn't...well, he's a big fat liar.

Comment: Anyway: maybe what he did was not academically correct, but it's himself he's not citing as well as you, so he must have had some reasons for it.  Moreover, given that your paper was published five years ago and has "many international citations," it seems that you have already won -- i.e., this work of yours was widely read and appreciated.  So this is not a lack of citation that causes you to lose priority or academic credit or anything like that.  If you pursue the point further, the only outcome I can see is to further fray your relationship with your former thesis advisor.

Comment: I have never heard in my life the story that a review paper must contain only papers of the last 2 years. This is not science. It seems as an excuse. I am disappointed because the truth is that he just forgot my work and this is not acceptable by a professor, who is also friend, as I thought.

Comment: You are making a fuss about nothing. Let it go. You can't force anyone to write the way you want. For some reason, he does not seem to think the work is relevant to his goals at this particular survey. It does not say anything about the quality of your reasearch and your friendship with him.

Comment: @Adriana: "I have never heard in my life the story that a review paper must contain only papers of the last 2 years." Me neither.  But you didn't answer my question: is it actually the case that all the references cited were published within the last two years?  If so, the chance that would happen by accident seems tiny.  "the truth is that he just forgot my work" How do you know the truth?  But if it is: he also forgot about his work, so he certainly made a mistake.  If you actually think he just made a mistake, what's your goal: to get him to admit it?...

Comment: Assuming all that: you gave him a chance to admit his mistake, and instead of doing so he's given some weird-sounding excuses.  So he's probably not feeling comfortable about it.  My experience in dealing with human beings (admittedly I'm a mathematician...) tells me that if you press the point now you'll just make things worse.  But if you can sincerely get over this rather small slight, then you have a good chance of continuing to have good dealings with him in the future.  Maybe five years from now he will apologize and you can laugh about it.

Comment: @Pete L. Clark Sorry I did not answer your question: so, no, the references cited are not from the last 2 years. I saw even references from 1975. Concerning what you say that he also forgot his work, my answer is yes, but still this isn't academically incorrect as well?? How can somebody be a respectable professor and forget his work, even if he participated by 10%? How can I trust him and continue work with him?

Comment: Is it possible the first author of the review paper wasn't aware of your work, or that it related so tangentially to his/her paper that adding your work would actually muddy the waters? Not every paper published on a  topic needs (or should) be added, unless the author wants to just to bolster the reference list - sometimes a picture is clearer with fewer brush strokes.

Comment: @Adriana: Thank you for providing that additional information; knowing that, I agree that your former advisor's response sounds completely ridiculous.  Concerning forgetting his own work: well, I imagine that for a review paper it's the first author who makes the list of references.  (I have to "imagine" because we don't have review papers in my field.)  As for the rest of what you're saying: again, we agree that this guy is in the wrong, but you seem to want to press for more than that.

Comment: You can continue to work with him if you think that this oversight is small compared to the advantages of future collaborations with him.  I really disagree that forgetting a reference to related work (i.e., a helpful reference rather than a necessary reference) is evidence that someone is not a "respectable professor," but it's up to you to judge.  The fact that he is giving you ridiculous excuses is much more of a concern.  Ultimately you have to decide whether you want to keep working with him, but even if you don't, pushing too hard on this is likely to be disadvantageous to both of you.

Comment: As I understand it, he is also a coauthor on the paper he has not cited? He might have written many more papers on a similar subject and hence decided that he would only cite his own articles from the last 2 years, to not come off as someone using a review to only showcase his own publication record. And as we do not have the original wording of his answers, but only a reproduction of what OP read into it (not to be offending, this is psychology and is what all people automatically do) I would be careful to say they are ridiculous excuses.

Comment: (1) When writing a review, there are always way more articles that could be cited than ones that in the end are actually cited. (2) Was the review article supposed to focus on recent developments (with a little backstory explaining the earlier references)? This is not uncommon in fast-moving fields. (3) How broadly cited is your article, and is it actually worthy of being cited in a review compared with other citations on your sub-topic? This is a tough one to swallow, but following up on item 1, you can['t cite every single article ever published.

Comment: "I am disappointed because the truth is that he just forgot my work and this is not acceptable by a professor, who is also friend, as I thought." to err is human; it is probably not a good idea to require such high standards from your friends and colleagues.  I agree with Pete that the response given by the prof was more of a concern, but then again it could be that he/she doesn't think the paper is worth citing, but doesn't want to tell you that explicitly.  Nepotism (unduly citing your students) would be far less what is expected of a "respectable professor".  Sometimes you just can't win!

Answer (score 6):

Agreeing with @PeteL.Clark: define precisely what you want as outcome of the interaction, and act following this outcome.

My experience of priority issues and fighting "not being cited" that, unless your work is so promising that a priority/citation fight warrants all-out war to gain or not lose visibility, the loss of concord is usually not worth it; as unfair as that may seem, the one complaining about being ignored is often seen as the one "disturbing the peace". It shouldn't be like that, but this is an empirical observation I made, even in blatant cases of intentional ignoring. Maybe it has something to do that quite a few times it's the ones with the most aggressive "nostrification" tendency who battle the issue of being ignored in the most forceful manner.

Now, there are indeed cases where all-out priority wars may be war-ranted (pun intended) to ensure that one is at least etched in the community's minds, but keep in mind, even then, the outcome is all but assured.

Lots of unfairness happens, to all of us, but it is usually the long-term that counts. Given that your old article attracted a lot of citations, you probably are better off just ignoring the matter, but only you can judge whether entering the war-ring (yes, pun intended again) as response to your latest slight is worth it.